# What are BesselJ functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

I solved an integration on mathematica which gives BesselJ functions and some other terms. I explored mathematica help and google but could not understand the difference between different types of bessel functions. Specially BesselJ function and its explicit form is my target.

Comment: It arises from solving certain types of second order differential equations with non constant coefficients. Are you familiar with diferential equations?

Comment: @science I know a little about differential equations. What I need here is to know about explicit form of besselJ functions.

Comment: You should take some time to read about [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Comment: I suggest you to ask more explicitly, since there are books on Bessel functions, and how should we know where to start? A nice little introduction to Bessel functions is the book by Bowman, "Introduction to Bessel functions".

Comment: @mickep thanx for giving me the name of book i ll b visitin it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$~\quad~$ [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) functions also appear in the following context: What happens when

we evaluate $($definite$)$ integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\lambda f\Big(g(x)\Big)~dx$, where $\big\{f,g\big\}\in\big\{\sin,~\sinh,$

$\cos,~\cosh\big\},~$ and $\lambda$ is either $\dfrac\pi2$ or $\infty$, depending on whether *g* is either a trigonometric or

a hyperbolic function. Thus, for $a>0$ we have the following identities:

---

> $$
> \int_0^\tfrac\pi2~\sin~\big(a~\sin x\big)~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2~\sin~\big(a~\cos x\big)~dx~=~\frac\pi2~H_0(a)
> \\
> \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \sinh\big(a~\sin x\big)~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sinh\big(a~\cos x\big)~dx~=~\frac\pi2~L_0(a)
> $$

---

> $$
> \int_0^\tfrac\pi2~\cos~\big(a~\sin x\big)~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2~\cos~\big(a~\cos x\big)~dx~=~\frac\pi2~J_0(a)
> \\
> \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \cosh\big(a~\sin x\big)~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\cosh\big(a~\cos x\big)~dx~=~\frac\pi2~I_0(a)
> $$

---

> $$\begin{align}
> \int_0^\infty\sin(a~\sinh x)~dx~&=~\quad\dfrac\pi2~\Big(I_0(a)-L_0(a)\Big)
> \\
> \int_0^\infty\sin(a~\cosh x)~dx~&=~\quad\dfrac\pi2\cdot J_0(a)
> \\
> \int_0^\infty\cos(a~\sinh x)~dx~&=~\quad~\quad~K_0(a)
> \\
> \int_0^\infty\cos(a~\cosh x)~dx~&=~-\dfrac\pi2\cdot Y_0(a)
> \end{align}$$

Comment: The latter four converge due to the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: Also, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\exp(-a~\cosh x)~dx~=~K_0(a).~$

Answer (score 19):

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ What are Bessel **J** functions ?

You are probably familiar with the fact that $e^x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$, right ? Well then, [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function)

are basically what happens when we ask ourselves, *“What is $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n!)^2}~$ ?”* But $(n!)^2=n!\cdot n!$,

so we then go a step further, by generalizing the question even more, and asking *“What is*

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!~(n+a)!}~$ *?”* This is more or less how the Bessel **I** function is born. Then we ask

ourselves, *“What would happen if the series were allowed to oscillate or alternate ?”, i.e.,*

*“What is $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!~(n+a)!}~$ ?”* And this is how the Bessel **J** function comes into existence.

Very similar to how $e^{-x}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$, for example.

---

> $$\begin{align}
> e^x&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}
> \\\\
> \bigg(1-\frac{\Gamma(a,x)}{\Gamma(a)}\bigg)~e^x&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+a}}{(n+a)!}
> \\\\
> I_a(2x)&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}~\frac{x^{n+a}}{(n+a)!}
> \\\\
> J_a(2x)&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}~\frac{x^{n+a}}{(n+a)!}~(-1)^n
> \\\\
> L_a(2x)&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+\frac12}}{\Big(n+\frac12\Big)!}~\frac{x^{n+\frac12+a}}{\Big(n+\frac12+a\Big)!}
> \\\\
> H_a(2x)&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+\frac12}}{\Big(n+\frac12\Big)!}~\frac{x^{n+\frac12+a}}{\Big(n+\frac12+a\Big)!}~(-1)^n
> \end{align}$$

---

See also [Struve functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) for more information. Speaking of which, notice that the last two

identities can be rewritten in the following $($non-standard, but rather intuitive$)$ manner :

---

> $$\begin{align}
> L_a(2x)&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=\tfrac12}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}~\frac{x^{n+a}}{(n+a)!}
> \\\\
> H_a(2x)&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=\tfrac12}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}~\frac{x^{n+a}}{(n+a)!}~(-1)^n
> \end{align}$$

Comment: So nice of you. Now I have at least an idea that where to go....

Comment: Perhaps you might also be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/610592/3).

Comment: There should be a way to center text on MSE! (Sorry a little off topic)