# Derivation of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik integral 3.876.1 (in question)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, bessel-functions, integration

In the Gradshteyn and Ryzhik Table of Integrals, the following integral appears (3.876.1, page 486 in the 8th edition):
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (p \sqrt{x^2 + a^2})}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} \cos (bx) dx =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2} J_0 \left( a \sqrt{p^2 - b^2} \right) & 0 < b < p \\
0 & b > p > 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for $a > 0$, where $J_0$ is the Bessel function.

I am interested how this result could be derived (not necessarily rigorously proved), especially the range of $p$ such that the value is $0$.

Thank you.

Comment: No it's not, check the $\sin$. Although it is not hard to do a change of variable for $p > 0$ and effectively normalize it to 1, so it's not too relevant.

Comment: in my edition, the note on bibliogrphay notation is the final page with roman numerals...ET I 26(30) is volume I of Erdelyi et al, Tables of Integral Transforms (1954), page 26, formula numbered (30). In turn, that may refer to something earlier.   http://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf

Comment: Let $x=a\sinh t$, followed by the [trigonometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#The_identities) for $\sin A\cos B$, further simplifications, and, ultimately, the [integral expressions for Bessel functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$I(a,b,p)\equiv\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(p\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\cos(bx)\,dx\\\\
$$

Enforcing the substitution $x\to a\sinh x$ and assuming that $a>0$ yields

$$\begin{align}
I(a,b,p)&=\int_0^{\infty}\sin\left(pa\cosh x\right)\cos(ba\sinh x)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\infty}\left(\sin\left(pa\cosh x+ba\sinh x\right)+\sin\left(pa\cosh x-ba\sinh x\right)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin\left(pa\cosh x+ba\sinh x\right)\,dx
\end{align}$$

Recalling that

$$A\cosh x+B\sinh x=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{A^2-B^2}\cosh(x-\text{artanh}(B/A))&,0<B<A\\\\
\sqrt{B^2-A^2}\sinh(x-\text{artanh}(A/B))&,B>A>0
\end{cases}
$$

we have

$$I(a,b,p)=
\begin{cases}
\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin\left(a\sqrt{p^2-b^2}\cosh x\right)\,dx&,0<b<p\\\\
\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin\left(a\sqrt{b^2-p^2}\sinh x\right)\,dx&,b>p>0
\end{cases}
$$

Noting that the integrand of the first integral is an even function of $x$, while the integrand of the second integral is an odd function of $x$ reveals

$$I(a,b,p)=
\begin{cases}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left(a\sqrt{p^2-b^2}\cosh x\right)\,dx&,0<b<p\\\\
0&,b>p>0
\end{cases}
$$

From Equation $(10.9.9)$ [HERE](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9#i), we see that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left(a\sqrt{p^2-b^2}\cosh x\right)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}J_0\left(a\sqrt{p^2-b^2}\right)$$

for $a\sqrt{p^2-b^2}>0$ and $p>b>0$

whereupon we have the final result

$$I(a,b,p)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}J_0\left(a\sqrt{p^2-b^2}\right)\,dx&,0<b<p\\\\
0&,b>p>0
\end{cases}
$$

for $a>0$.

Comment: Very nice ! (+1)
To make the answer even more complete, you could add a proof of 10.9.9 if you can...?!

Comment: @Dr.MV This exactly answers my question, thank you! If possible/you are aware (I know this was not part of the original question) could you explain "why" there is such singular behavior at $p = b$? Is there some intuition that could have hinted such behavior? If not, I will gladly accept the answer as is.

Comment: @questions You're welcome!  My pleasure.  When $p=b$, we have $\cosh x+\sinh x = e^x$ and the integral $$I(a,b,b)=\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(pa\cosh x+ab \sinh x)dx=\frac12\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$$Thus, the value is average of the left-side and right-side limits.  This is caused from the transition of a function going from even to odd.

Comment: @Dr.MV Is there something that can be said about the original integral, pre-substitution? I mean that we can set $b = 1$ by doing substitution, so that the same singular behavior can be seen in \begin{equation} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(p \sqrt{x^2 + a^2})}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} \cos x dx \end{equation}. Is there something special that can be seen in this integral, without substitutions, at $p = 1$, or to expect some sort of transition at $p = 1$?

Comment: @questions While with experience one might be able to "see" a discontinuity at $p=1$, I do not have the insight or foresight to deduce this by inspection alone.  And without analysis, including numerical/empirical, the "magical" change in the value of the integral's going from $0$ at $p=.99999$ to $\approx. \pi/2$ at $p=1.000001$ does not appear obvious to me.

Comment: @Mark Viola : Why $I(a,b,p)=
\begin{cases}
\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin\left(a\sqrt{p^2-b^2}\cosh x\right)\,dx&,0<b<p\\\\
\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin\left(a\sqrt{b^2-p^2}\sinh x\right)\,dx&,b>p>0
\end{cases}$ ? Where did $\operatorname{arctanh}(A/B)$ (or $\operatorname{arctanh}(B/A)$) disappear to?

Comment: @Plantation The terms are just translations in the hyperbolic cosine.  Just make a simple substitution and they "disappear" since the integration is over the entire set of reals.

Comment: @Mark Viola : Thanks! I have a feeling.