# What is the integral to $\int \frac{\sin \left( xt\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{t} \, dt$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, bessel-functions, integration

I know from this question that [Derivation of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik integral 3.876.1 (in question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376303/derivation-of-gradshteyn-and-ryzhik-integral-3-876-1-in-question/1376461#1376461)

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( x\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2} J_{0}(ax), \quad (a>0, \ x>0)$

What are the integrals to:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( xt\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{t} \, dt = ?, \quad (a>0, \ x>0)$

$\int_{n}^{m} \frac{\sin \left( xt\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{t} \, dt = ?, \quad (a>0, \ x>0,  \ m > n > 0)$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Please don't add a newly created tag to many questions at once. And whenever you want to create a new tag, it's preferable to post first in the [Tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019?answertab=active#tab-top) to see what other users think of the tag. Alternatively, there is also a [dedicated chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/tagging).

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

*hint* consider first and second derivation with respect to $x$