# Trying to solve $I=\int_c^\infty {\sin \big(x+{k \over x} \big) \over x}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration, leibniz-integral-rule

While trying to find an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882045/closed-form-for-int-infty-infty-frac-sinb-x-sin-sqrtax2x-s) problem on the forum, I came across this integral:

$$ I=\int_c^\infty {\sin \big(x+{k \over x} \big) \over x}dx \tag 1$$

Where $c$ and $k$ are real numbers. I tried to solve this using Feynamn's trick. I defined a parameter $p$ such that:

$$\overline I (p)=\int_c^\infty {\sin \big(px+{k \over x} \big) \over x}dx \tag 2$$

Taking the derivative of $\overline I$ with respect to $p$ I get:

$$\overline I'=\int_c^\infty {\cos \big(px+{k \over x} \big)}dx \tag 3$$

To get rid of one constant in the cosine, I used the substitution $t=px$ and got:

$$\overline I'={1 \over p}\int_{pc}^\infty {\cos \big(t+{kp \over t} \big)}dt \tag 4$$

By grouping the constants as $cp = b$ and $kp = q$ we get:

$$\overline I'={1 \over p}\int_{b}^\infty {\cos \big(t+{q \over t} \big)}dt \tag 5$$

The next thing I did was use the Euler trigonometric identity to write:

$$\overline I'={1 \over 2p}\int_{b}^\infty \Bigg ( e^{i \big(t+{q \over t} \big)} + e^{-i \big(t+{q \over t} \big)} \Bigg ) dt  \tag 6$$

Here I got stuck. I would appreciate some help in solving this problem.

Comment: The integral fails to converge, you should add some exponentially decaying terms to proceed

Comment: My thoughts are the same now. I just tried using the Taylor series to expand the sine function at the beginning of the equation and then using the binomial theorem I finally got an expression I can find the integral of. However, it does seem to diverge.