# Integrals with error function and exponentials

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm trying to solve the integrals below:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot \operatorname{erf}\left(m\cdot\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) \cdot \exp(-a\cdot (x-b)^2-a\cdot (y-c)^2)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$
where $a,b,c$ and $m$ are constants. Does anybody know how to solve the integral? Thanks!

Comment: I edited your post to make it readable, please check if this fits your question.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly my integral. Thanks!

Comment: with $b=c=0$ probably yes (0!) otherwise i would be really surprised

Comment: However, b and c are not 0.

Comment: First of all, you should differentiate with regard to the parameter *m*, to get rid of the $\dfrac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ in the integrand. Secondly, the very presence of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in the exponent *begs* for a trigonometric or hyperbolic substitution. Unfortunately, the only functions which are [defined in this way](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401) are the [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) functions.

Comment: I have tried what you said. First let the integral equal to I(m), and then differentiate over m. Through this, I can get ride of the sqrt(x^2+y^2). But then, I got quite complex exponentials. I was stuck again.