# How to solve an integral with a fractional order.

Tags: improper-integrals, laplace-transform, complex-integration, bessel-functions, fractional-calculus

How should I find a value of these integrals:
$$
A:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{(x+1)^{2-\nu}x^{\nu}}dx
\quad\text{and}\quad
B:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{(x+1)^{1-\nu}x^{\nu}}dx,
$$
where $\nu\in(0,1)$.

Because I asked about a problem as having resembled this before ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448203/find-a-value-of-a-strange-improper-integral)), I have tried to solve by the same argument, i.e., using the Laplace transform but I haven't found the formula for the Laplace transform.
I also have attacked by the method via the complex integral (which appears in the Fourier transform) but it didn't work well.
I guess that Bessel functions appear as the solution.
However, I don't know how a solution (with Bessel functions) is provided if I do it.

I'm glad if you give a solution as possible in detail.

Thank you.

Comment: According to Mathematica the MeijerG is involved, so I'd start looking in the tables for integral representations for this function.

Comment: Thank you for comment. How is the form of solution by Mathematica?

Comment: `(2^-n MeijerG[{{n/2, (1 + n)/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2, 1}, {0}}, 1/
  4])/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[2 - n])` for the first one, and `(2^(-1 - n)
  MeijerG[{{n/2, (1 + n)/2}, {}}, {{0, 1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, 1/
  4])/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1 - n])` for the second one. Here, $n=\nu$.

Comment: In order for [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) to appear, we must have some “nice” values of $\nu~($such as integers or half-integers$)$, and even then it is not guaranteed; and if even that fails to hold, then $($ [generalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) $)$ [hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) are unavoidable.