# Problem with definite integral $\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\sin \left(\arctan \left(x\right)+x\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Need to calculate this definite integral. It's seems very strange for me
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\sin \left(\arctan\left(x\right)+x\right)dx$$

I dont see any reasonable way to calculate this integral. For instance, arctan of π/2 - it's incomprehensible value. I think there are some clever and special way.

Comment: Question. Why would $\arctan{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ be an incomprehensible value?

Comment: PersonaNonGrata probably means that the arctan(pi/2) is not one of the standard trig values that everyone memorizes when they take analysis/calculus/trig.

Comment: I think the OP means that usually we de not see the domain of $\arctan$ as angles. However, $\arctan(\pi/2)$ is well defined !

Comment: PersonaNonGrata, are you contour integrals from complex analysis in your class?  Maybe there's a way to reinterpret this integral in that setting.

Comment: Perhaps this is a substitution problem.  Try u:=arctan(x), and rewrite dx in terms of du.  Notice that the function becomes sin(u+tan(u)) and dx becomes ((tan(u))^2+1)du.

Comment: both maple and wolfram can't find it, even the definite integral

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien Really? [Wolfram alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28arctan%28x%29%2Bx%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2&x=0&y=0) tell me that is approx. 1.15727.

Comment: @Asydot you are right, I guess I only tried the indefinite integral on wolfram.

Comment: i think there is no expression in the known elementary functions for this integral

Comment: I mean if tan (π / 4) or tan (π / 6) is something "natural", the arctan of the same quantities are something incomprehensible. :)) Kind of like $\sin 3\sqrt2$: number makes sense but it is "artificial" as $3\sqrt2$ normally looks like sine value and not like argument.

Comment: @SinisterCutlass replacing $u = arctanx$ hardly something to give. We obtain the integral of $\frac{sin(u+tanu)}{1+u^2}$, and what to do with it?

Comment: @PersonaNonGrata if $u=arctan(x)$, then $du=\frac{1}{1+x^2} dx$, so $dx=(1+x^2)du=((1+(tan(u))^2)du$...... Now, $1+(tan(u))^2=(sec(u))^2$, and note that $\frac{d}{du} (tan(u)+u)=(sec(u))^2+1$.  After this, maybe your integral can be attacked with ordinary substitution or integration by parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the upper limit were $\infty$ instead of $\dfrac\pi2$ , then the result would be expressible in terms of [Bessel **I**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve **L** functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function). To prove this, first use the famous trigonometric formula for $\sin(a+b)$, then simplify $\sin(\arctan x)$ and $\cos(\arctan x)$, and rewrite $x\cos x+\sin x$ as the derivative of $x\sin x$, followed by integration by parts. Lastly, write $x^2=(x^2+1)-1$ to split up the integral into two nicer ones, and employ [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401) to evaluate both of them. As it stands, however, the expression cannot be parsed even in terms of such special functions, unless, of course, one were to allow the existence of “incomplete” Bessel and Struve functions.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(\tan^{-1}x+x)~dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\tan^{-1}x\cos x~dx+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\tan^{-1}x\sin x~dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{x\cos x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}~dx+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}~dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{2(2n)!\sqrt{x^2+1}}~d(x^2+1)+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!\sqrt{x^2+1}}~dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(x^2+1-1)^n}{2(2n)!\sqrt{x^2+1}}~d(x^2+1)+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(x^2+1-1)^n}{2(2n+1)!\sqrt{x^2+1}}~d(x^2+1)$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{C_k^n(-1)^{2n-k}(x^2+1)^k}{2(2n)!\sqrt{x^2+1}}~d(x^2+1)+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{C_k^n(-1)^{2n-k}(x^2+1)^k}{2(2n+1)!\sqrt{x^2+1}}~d(x^2+1)$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(x^2+1)^{k-\frac{1}{2}}}{2(2n)!k!(n-k)!}~d(x^2+1)+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(x^2+1)^{k-\frac{1}{2}}}{2(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!}~d(x^2+1)$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(x^2+1)^{k+\frac{1}{2}}}{2(2n)!k!(n-k)!\left(k+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{2}+\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(x^2+1)^{k+\frac{1}{2}}}{2(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!\left(k+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{2}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(\pi^2+2)^{k+\frac{1}{2}}}{2^{k+\frac{1}{2}}(2n)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(\pi^2+2)^{k+\frac{1}{2}}}{2^{k+\frac{1}{2}}(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!}{(2n)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}$