# Have these bounds on Bessel function root spacing been proven?

Tags: roots, special-functions, bessel-functions

Looking at the [roots of the Bessel functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.21) (particularly the [Bessel functions of the first kind, $J_\nu(x)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2)), it seems that a lot is known. [Poking around WolframAlpha plots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B+%7B+BesselJzeros%5Bx,2%5D+-+BesselJzeros%5Bx,1%5D,+BesselJzeros%5Bx,3%5D+-+BesselJzeros%5Bx,2%5D,++Pi%7D,+%7Bx,+-2,+5%7D%5D), I have observed a couple of patterns in the spacing of adjacent roots, and I wanted to know if they've been proven in general or not. If $j_{\nu,n}$, $n \ge 1$, is the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ positive zero of $J_\nu(x)$, then $\forall\ |\nu| \ge \frac{1}{2}$:
\begin{align}
    j_{\nu,n+1}-j_{\nu,n} &\ge \pi \\
    j_{\nu,n+1}-j_{\nu,n} &\ge j_{\nu,n+2}-j_{\nu,n+1},
\end{align}
with the inequalities reversing for $|\nu| < \frac{1}{2}$, but not by much.

The [reference linked](https://archive.org/details/ATreatiseOnTheTheoryOfBesselFunctions) in an 
[answer to a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1518785/153694) about Bessel function roots  has on the bottom of page 492 (502 in pdf numbering) that for functions of the form
$$\mathcal{C}_\nu(x) \equiv J_\nu(x) \cos\alpha - Y_\nu(x) \sin\alpha$$
with $\nu > \frac{1}{2}$ the roots that exceed $\frac{(2\nu+1)(2\nu+3)}{\pi}$ are bounded by the intervals
$$\left(m\pi - \alpha + \frac{\nu\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2},\ m\pi - \alpha + \frac{\nu\pi}{2} + \frac{3\pi}{4}\right)$$
for some integers $m$ (note that I cannot find any guarantee that the $m$ in this formula will correspond to the $n$ indexing the zeros, overall).

The [limiting form of $J_\nu(x)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.7#ii) certainly implies that the spacing has to trend to $\pi$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, I know of no proof about whether that trend is from above or below.

Sorry, I'm rambling because it's late. Point being - are these properties provable?

Comment: "the spacing has to trend to π" - considering the [known asymptotic behavior](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17) of the Bessel functions for large argument, that is something reasonable to think of. You might wish to look up work by Luigi Gatteschi on the zeroes of cylinder functions.