# Asymptotics of zeros of Bessel functions

Tags: reference-request, roots, special-functions, bessel-functions

Let $J_\nu(x):=\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k(x/2)^{\nu+2k}}{k!~\Gamma(\nu+k+1)}$ denote a [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). When $\nu\geq0$, let $0<j_{\nu,1}<j_{\nu,2}<\cdots$ denote the [positive zeroes of $J_\nu(x)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionZeros.html). From this MSE [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518358/zeros-of-bessel-functions), one gets an asymptotic form of $j_{\nu, k}$ for large $k$ and fixed $\nu$ (see also MacMahon's asymptotic formula [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.21)). My question is:

> Keeping $k$ fixed, are there asymptotic formulae (or lower bounds) for $j_{\nu, k}$ for large positive $\nu$?

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have a look at https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82806344.pdf

Comment: It looks like the formula 10.21.41 from the last [link](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.21) is what you want.