# What is $\sin(\cos(x))$?

Tags: trigonometry

As the title asks, what is $\sin(\cos(x))$.  I want it to be reduced more, if possible.  I don't know where to start.  I could manipulate the expression in many ways, but none allow me to remove either the $\sin$ or $\cos$.  For example:$$\sin(\cos(x))=\sqrt{1-(\cos(\cos(x))^2}$$

Then I'd need to know what $\cos(\cos(x))$ is.  Anyways, I want to know if this is solvable such that I don't have a trig function inside another trig function, and a solution if one such exists.

Comment: normally in engineering, sin or cos in another sin or cos has no practical application. But theoretically you can use it, however forget the conceptual view anymore.

Comment: Well, for all practical purposes the answer is "no, it's not possible to make that not have nested trig function" unless you're willing to trade that for infinite series.

Comment: How do you want to express it?

Comment: $\frac12 i e^{-\frac12 i (e^{-i x}+e^{i x})}-\frac12 i e^{\frac12 i (e^{-i x}+e^{i x})}$

Comment: It appears to be very close to $(\sin(1)) \cdot \cos x$, but not exactly

Comment: I don't think there's any (good) way to express this without embedded trig functions.  I think the most meaningful thing you can say is that, for a given angle, $\cos$ turns it into the adjacent length in the relevant triangle, and then we put that length into $\sin$ as if it were an angle.  But that's pretty meaningless.

Comment: When you say a solution, do you mean solving $\sin (\cos x)=0$?  If so this would be equivalent to solving $\cos x = n\pi$.

Comment: You could expand it in a power series.  That would give you a good way to approximate it to whatever accuracy you like.  A power series around $x=0$ has a bunch of $\sin(1)$'s and $\cos(1)$'s which are hard to evaluate but at $x=\pi/2$ the power series expansion is $-(x-\pi/2)+(1/3)(x-\pi/2)^3-(1/10)(x-\pi/2)^5 +\cdots$.

Comment: The graph of sin(cos x) looks very much like an ordinary sine wave...  is that an illusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said in comments and answers, you cannot do much with embedded trigonometirc functions except developing as Taylor series.

Built around $x=0$ (remember that, for any $x$, $|\cos(x)| \leq 1$), you should get

$$\sin(\cos(x))=\sin (1)-\frac{1}{2} x^2 \cos (1)+x^4 \left(\frac{\cos (1)}{24}-\frac{\sin
   (1)}{8}\right)+x^6 \left(\frac{\sin (1)}{48}+\frac{7 \cos (1)}{360}\right)+x^8
   \left(\frac{\sin (1)}{960}-\frac{209 \cos (1)}{40320}\right)+x^{10}
   \left(\frac{1259 \cos (1)}{3628800}-\frac{193 \sin
   (1)}{241920}\right)+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$

$$\cos(\cos(x))=\cos (1)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \sin (1)-x^4 \left(\frac{\sin (1)}{24}+\frac{\cos
   (1)}{8}\right)+x^6 \left(\frac{\cos (1)}{48}-\frac{7 \sin (1)}{360}\right)+x^8
   \left(\frac{209 \sin (1)}{40320}+\frac{\cos (1)}{960}\right)-x^{10}
   \left(\frac{1259 \sin (1)}{3628800}+\frac{193 \cos
   (1)}{241920}\right)+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$

Comment: One might also be inclined to take a Fourier series, given that $\sin(\cos(x))$ is periodic. I just suggest this since that's a little more natural for a periodic function than Taylor expansion (though the coefficients are harder to compute; Mathematica insists they have a closed form in terms of the Bessel function though)

Comment: @MiloBrandt. I totally agree with you !

Answer (score 2):

Rationalizing $\cos (x)$ in function of $\tan (x/2)=t$ you have $\cos (x)=\frac {1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ hence $\sin(\cos (x))=\sin(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})$ and you can if you want to developpe as Taylor series this last expression.

Comment: This is a good idea, indeed ! $+1$

Comment: You are very welcome. This leads to nice Taylor series $$\sin(\cos (x))=\sin (1)-2 t^2 \cos (1)+t^4 (2 \cos (1)-2 \sin (1))+t^6 \left(4 \sin (1)-\frac{2 \cos
   (1)}{3}\right)+O\left(t^7\right)$$ $$\cos(\cos (x))=\cos (1)+2 t^2 \sin (1)-2 t^4 (\sin (1)+\cos (1))+t^6 \left(\frac{2 \sin (1)}{3}+4
   \cos (1)\right)+O\left(t^7\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

> *I want it to be reduced more, if possible.*

Not possible.

> *I want to know if this is solvable such that I don't have a trig function inside another trig function, and a solution if one such exists.*

Not “solvable”, and no such simplified solution exists.

---

The only remotely interesting thing I can come up with concerning this topic is that $$\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sin(\sin x)~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sin(\cos x)~dx~=~\frac\pi2~H_0(1),$$ and $$\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\cos(\cos x)~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\cos(\sin x)~dx~=~\frac\pi2~J_0(1).$$ See [Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) functions for more [information](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401).