# Integral with $\cos$ and $\sin$

Tags: complex-analysis

2 integrals to calculate:$\int_0 ^{2\pi} e^{\sin\phi}\sin(n\phi -\sin (\phi))d\phi$

$\int_0 ^{2\pi} e^{\cos\phi}\cos(n\phi -\cos (\phi))d\phi$

I tried to make a substitution:$\cos \phi=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$
$\sin \phi=\frac{z-z^{-1}}{i2}$. And by the hint I will get to
$\int_D e^zz^{-(n+1)}dz$,    $D:=\{|z|<1\}$.
But I am confused with this part: $\cos(n\phi -\cos (\phi))$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be very generous if you could show ur own efforts...

Comment: for what stands $n$ here?

Comment: $n$ stands for "do $n$ot use maple and/or mathematica"

Comment: I would really like to,but got lost at the beginning. Could you just tell me how to substitute confusing part? 'n' is without limits.

Answer (score 1):

**Too long for a comment:** Even if by absurd any of these integrals were to actually possess a

closed form, it will most likely be in terms of [Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) functions. I write this because

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}e^{a\sin x}~dx~=~\int_0^{2\pi}e^{a\cos x}~dx~=~2\pi~I_0(a),~$ while $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\sin(nx-\sin x)~dx$ can be written

in terms of $\pi~H_{-|n|}(1),~$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\cos(nx-\cos x)~dx$ can be expressed in terms of $\pi~J_n(1)$ for

even values of $n=2m,~$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\cos(nx-\cos x)~dx$ can be parsed in terms of $\dfrac\pi2~H_{-|n|}(1)$

for odd values of $n=2m+1.~$ More information on this topic can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401).

Comment: Do you know if there is a closed form for $\int_0^\frac\pi2\cos(ut+v\sin(t))dt;u,v\in\Bbb R$?