# Maximum of a function defined via a definite integral

Tags: calculus

exploring a problem I have introduced a function:

$$I(x)=\int_0^{\pi/2}xe^{-x\sin t} dt.$$

To my surprise the maximum of the function appears to be achieved at a value seemingly equal to $e$. I have checked it by computing the derivative of the function:

$$\frac{dI}{dx}=\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-x\sin t}(1-x\sin t)\ dt$$
by an  online integrator and have got $x_{\rm max}\approx0.9996e$. I am not however aware of the possible integration errors of the routine.

Could you please check it with a  tool providing not only the result of the integration but also its error? Of course an analytical proof of the equality or inequality would be even more appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$ I(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\,e^{-x\sin t}\,dt = \frac{\pi x}{2}\left(I_0(x)-L_0(x)\right) $$
where $I_0$ and $L_0$ are a Bessel and a Struve function. The fact that a zero of
$$ I'(x) = \left(I_0(x)-L_0(x)\right) + x\left(I_1(x)-L_{-1}(x)\right) $$
occurs very close to $e$ probably depends on the continued fraction expansion of $I_0$ and $L_0$. However, $e$ is not an exact zero:
$$ I'(e) \approx -0.0000519.$$

Answer (score 2):

The integral has the closed form (given by Maple)
$$I(x)=\int_0^{\pi/2}x e^{-x \sin t}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}x \left( I_0(x) -\mathbf{L_0}(x)\right)$$
with the modified Bessel and Struve functions, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25 and http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.2. With this closed form you can solve $I'(x)=0$ and get the maximum at $x_m=2.71729791967257323761$ with $x_m-e\approx -0.0009839$

Answer (score 1):

> $$x_\max\simeq2.717297919672573237610594072000\ldots$$

Also, the integral evaluates to $~\dfrac\pi2~x~\Big[I_0(x)-L_0(x)\Big].~$ See [Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) functions for more [information](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401).

Answer (score 1):

$$I(x)=\int_0^{\pi/2}xe^{-x\sin t} dt=\frac{1}{2} \pi  x (I_0(x)-\pmb{L}_0(x))$$ where appear Bessel and Struve functions. For the derivative $$I'(x)=\frac{1}{2} \pi  (-x \pmb{L}_{-1}(x)-\pmb{L}_0(x)+I_0(x)+x I_1(x))$$ it cancels for $x\approx 2.71729791967200$ which is very close to $e$ but not identical.