# the integral a complex variable

Tags: integration, complex-integration

$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos\varphi}(\cos\varphi-\sin\varphi)d\varphi$

I think

$e^{i\varphi}=z$ $\to d\varphi=\frac{dz}{iz}$

$\cos\varphi=\frac{z^2+1}{2z}$

$\sin\varphi=\frac{z^2-1}{2iz}$

$\oint\limits_{|z|=1}^{}e^{\frac{z^2+1}{2z}}\left(\frac{z^2+1}{2z}-\frac{z^2-1}{2iz}\right)dz$

$z=0$    -  essential singularity

We need to be expanded in a Laurent but I do not know how there are so many polchaetsya values at $\frac{1}{z}$

Comment: what is it *polchaetsya* values?

Comment: Please don't number questions i.e. "complex integration **5**". They do not make good titles.

Comment: The integral $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\cos \phi}\,\cos \phi=2\pi I_1(1)$, where $I_1(z)$ is the [First Kind Modified Bessel Function of order $1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1).

Comment: not quite clear

Answer (score 0):

Mark that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{cos \phi}\sin\phi d\phi =\int_1^1e^ydy=0 \text{ (no singularities)},$$
so the artifical transformations
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{cos \phi}(\cos\phi-\sin\phi) d\phi = \int_0^{2\pi}e^{cos \phi}(\cos\phi + i\sin\phi) d\phi = \int_0^{2\pi}e^{cos \phi}e^{i\phi} d\phi$$
easy the task

Comment: not quite sure where it came from $+isin\varphi$

Comment: we can add zero

Answer (score 0):

> $$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\cos\varphi}(\cos\varphi-\sin\varphi)~d\varphi~=~2\int_0^\pi e^{\cos\varphi}\cos\varphi~d\varphi~=~2\pi~I_1(1).$$

See [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for more [information](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401).

Comment: did not quite understand what $I_1(1)$

Comment: @Olya12: Click the links and find out...