# Series expansion of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Consider the function $I(y)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \mathrm{d} x$. I'd like to see the leading order term of $I(y)$ about $y=0$, so I expand the integrand:
$$
e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=e^{-x}-e^{-x}\frac{1}{2x}y^2+e^{-x}\frac{1+x}{8x^3}y^4+\dots
$$
However, only the integral of the $0^\mathrm{th}$ order term converges (to $1$ of course). How would one proceed here to find the second order term (or higher)?

Answer (score 3):

As simple hyperbolic substitution of the form $x=y\sinh t$ yields $I(y)=|y|~K_1\Big(|y|\Big),$ see [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for more [information](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401). Its series expansions around the origin can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuZPo.png).

Comment: I was looking at this last night and arrived at your result.  But I was unsatisfied that I was unable to develop the series expansion for the modified Bessel function directly from either of the integral representations.  To facilitate the expansion, one must, I believe, return to the ODE or deform the contour in the complex plane in which yet another integral representation is used.  It might be useful here to post a way forward.  - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: I was thinking about using the definition of the Bessel K function from the Wikipedia page, in conjunction with Euler's reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function, and l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: That will almost surely work.  But I thought that I'd try developing the expansion from elementary principles - brute force so to speak.  If you have a moment, I'd like your thoughts on the answer I posted herein.  - Mark

Comment: These answers are both helpful, so thank you. I also have a more complicated integral that also resists the naïve series expansion as well as simplification via hyperbolic substitution. Is there a general approach for problems like these, or could you recommend a reference that covers some helpful techniques?

Comment: @CommanderEllenTigh I don't know of a fully robust approach to determining a series.  By the way ... there is a fatal flaw in the approach I outlined.  We omitted the most of the terms in the expansion of $e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and the integrals of these terms do have components that are $O\left(|y|^2\right)$.  However, none of these omitted terms are of order $\log (|y|)\,|y|^2$. So, the expansion is valid up to order $\log (|y|)\,|y|^2$.

Comment: Here's another case: replace the integrand with $$x \log\left( 1+e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$ Is there a substitution like Lucian's that brings us to a special function?

Comment: @CommanderEllenTigh: $d(x^2+y^2)=2x~dx.$

Comment: @CommanderEllenTigh: The final result is $-|y|~\text{Li}_2\Big(-e^{-|y|}\Big)-\text{Li}_3\Big(-e^{-|y|}\Big).$

Answer (score 3):

Let $I(y)$ be the integral of interest given by

$$\begin{align}
I(y)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{|y|} e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx+\int_{|y|}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

---

For the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$, we note that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le \sqrt{2}|y|$.  Therefore, inasmuch as we are developing an asymptotic series for "small" $|y|$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{|y|} e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^{|y|}\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{n/2}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n|y|^{n+1}}{n!}\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec^{n+2}\theta \,d\theta\\\\
&=|y|-\left(\frac{\sqrt 2 +\log\left(1+\sqrt 2\right)}{2}\right)|y|^2+\frac23 |y|^3+O\left(|y|^4\right) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

---

To facilitate evaluation of the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$, we expand the exponential as

$$\begin{align}
e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}&=e^{-x}-\frac12 y^2\frac{e^{-x}}{x}+\frac18 y^4\frac{(x+1)e^{-x}}{x^3}+O\left(y^6\right)\\\\
&=e^{-x}-\frac12 y^2\frac{e^{-x}}{x}+\frac18 y^4\frac{e^{-x}}{x^2}+\frac18 y^4\frac{e^{-x}}{x^3}+O\left(y^6\right) \tag 3\\\\
\end{align}$$

---

Next, we write the integral of the first term on the right-hand side of $(3)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\int_{|y|}^\infty e^{-x}\,dx&=e^{-|y|}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n|y|^n}{n!}\\\\
&=1-|y|+\frac12 |y|^2-\frac16 |y|^3+O\left(|y|^4\right) \tag 4
\end{align}$$

---

We write the integral of the second term is

$$\begin{align}
-\frac12 |y|^2\,\int_{|y|}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}x\,dx&=-\frac12 |y|^2\,\left(\int_{|y|}^1 \frac{e^{-x}}x\,dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}x\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\frac12 \log (|y|)\,|y|^2-\frac12 \left(\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}x\,dx-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n\,n!}\right)\,|y|^2-\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}|y|^{n+2}}{n\,n!}\\\\
&=\frac12 \log (|y|)\,|y|^2+\frac12 \gamma\,|y|^2-\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}|y|^{n+2}}{n\,n!}\\\\
&=\frac12 \log (|y|)\,|y|^2+\frac12 \gamma\,|y|^2-\frac12 |y|^3+O\left(|y|^4\right) \tag 5
\end{align}$$

---

Using integration by parts, we find the third integral on the right-hand side of $(3)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\frac18 |y|^4\,\int_{|y|}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x^2}\,dx&=\frac18 |y|^4\left(\frac{e^{-|y|}}{|y|}\right)-\frac18 |y|^4\,\int_{|y|}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac18 e^{-|y|}|y|^3+\log (|y|)|y|^4+\frac18 \gamma |y|^4-\frac18 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}|y|^{n+4}}{n\,n!}\\\\
&=\frac18 |y|^3+O\left(\log(|y|)\,|y|^4\right) \tag 6
\end{align}$$

---

Using integration by parts twice, we find the fourth integral on the right-hand side of $(3)$ as

$$\frac18\,|y|^4\int_{|y|}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x^3}\,dx=-\frac1{16}|y|^2-\frac18|y|^3+O\left(\log(|y|)\,|y|^4\right)\tag 7$$

---

Putting together results from $(2)$ and $(4)-(7)$, we obtain so far

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx=1+\left(\frac{\log(|y|)+\gamma -\log(1+\sqrt 2)-(1-\sqrt 2)}{2}\right)\,y^2+O(y^4)}\tag 8$$

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

In $(3)$, we have omitted terms beyond $\frac18 y^4\frac{e^{-x}}{x^3}$.  These terms will have a component that is of order $|y|^2$ and as such, the expansion in $(8)$ as written, is not correct.

However, the expansion is correct up to order $\log(|y|)\,|y|^2$.  On way to complete the expansion up to order $|y|^2$ is to use the [Faa di Bruno Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) to write the full expansion of $(3)$.

Comment: Nicely done. Probably more correct than mine.

Comment: @martycohen Well, thank you.  But, there is a fatal flaw in my approach.  The omitted terms actually contribute to the coefficient on $y^2$.  The expansion is only valid for order $\log(y)\,y^2$.  Perhaps using the Faa di Bruno formula would be helpful for carrying out the full expansion, but this might be more challenging than I am thinking.

Answer (score 1):

If
$x^2+y^2
=r^2
$,
$2x dx
=2r dr
$
or
$dx
=\frac{r dr}{x}
=\frac{r dr}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}
$

$\begin{align}
I(y)
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx\\
&=\int_y^\infty e^{-r}\frac{r dr}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}\\
&=\int_1^\infty e^{-ys}\frac{ys y ds}{\sqrt{y^2s^2-y^2}}
\qquad r = ys, dr = yds\\
&=y\int_1^\infty e^{-ys}\frac{s ds}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}\\
&=y\int_1^\infty e^{-ys}\frac{ ds}{\sqrt{1-1/s^2}}\\
&=y\int_1^\infty e^{-ys}(1-1/s^2)^{-1/2}ds\\
&=y\int_1^\infty e^{-ys}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}\frac{ds}{s^{2n}}\\
&=y\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}\int_1^\infty e^{-ys}s^{-2n}ds\\
&=y\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}y^{2n-1}\int_1^\infty e^{-ys}(ys)^{-2n}yds\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}y^{2n}\int_y^\infty e^{-t}t^{-2n}dt\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}y^{2n}\Gamma(-2n+1,y)\\
\end{align}
$

From
http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4
we have
$\Gamma(-n,z)
=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}(E_{1}(z)-e^{-z}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k}k!}{z^{k+1}})
$
where
$E_{1}(z)
=\int_{z}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
y^{2n}\Gamma(-2n+1,y)
&=y^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}(E_{1}(z)-e^{-z}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}\frac{(-1)^{k}k!}{y^{k+1}})\\
&=-\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}(y^{2n}E_{1}(y)-e^{-y}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^{k}k!y^{2n-k-1})\\
&=-\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}(y^{2n}E_{1}(y)-e^{-y}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^{2n-2-k}(2n-2-k)!y^{2n-(2n-2-k)-1})\\
&=-\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}(y^{2n}E_{1}(y)-e^{-y}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^{k}(2n-2-k)!y^{k+1})\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$E_{1}(z)
\sim\frac{e^{-z}}{z}\left(1-\frac{1!}
{z}+\frac{2!}{z^{2}}-\frac{3!}{z^{3}}+\cdots\right)
$,
we have
$y^{2n}E_{1}(y)
\sim y^{2n-1}e^{-y}\left(1-\frac{1!}
{y}+\frac{2!}{y^{2}}-\frac{3!}{y^{3}}+\cdots\right)
$.

Also,
since
$(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}
=\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}
$,
we finally get

$\begin{array}\\
I(y)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}y^{2n}\Gamma(-2n+1,y)\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}\left(y^{2n}E_{1}(y)-e^{-y}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^{k}(2n-2-k)!y^{k+1}\right)\right)\\
&\sim-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}\left(y^{2n-1}e^{-y}-e^{-y}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^{k}(2n-2-k)!y^{k+1}\right)\right)\\
&=-e^{-y}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}(2n-1)!}\left(y^{2n-1}-
\sum_{k=0}^{2n-2}(-1)^{k}(2n-2-k)!y^{k+1}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

with the last
approximation using
$y^{2n}E_{1}(y)
\sim y^{2n-1}e^{-y}
$.

As usual,
with this complexity,
$P(error)
> 1-\frac1{e}
$,
but I think that
something like this
should hold.

Comment: This is a nice effort.  A couple of thoughts.  The final result is not a power series due to the appearance of the factor of $e^{-y}$.  The use of the relationships among well-known and established functions is a way forward through this.  But from a purely pedagogical perspective, I'm not sure if our relying on other series expansions  (Where did they come from after all?) is "fit-for-purpose" instructive here.  But +1 for the amazing effort.  - Mark

Comment: Just use $e^{-y}=1-y+...$ .

Comment: Of course.  But then one needs to multiply the series.