# Help with evaluating an improper integral

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t\sqrt t}e^{-1/t-pt} \, dt$$
$\operatorname{Re}(p)>0$

Comment: If I am reading things right, the exponential term is constant, in which case there is a serious divergence problem for $\int_0^1$.

Comment: my mistake sorry i've edited

Comment: In general, for positive value of *a* and *b*, we have $$\int_0^\infty\exp\bigg(-a^2t-\dfrac{b^2}t\bigg)~\dfrac{dt}{t^{n+1}} ~=~ 2\bigg(\dfrac ab\bigg)^n~K_n(2ab),$$ see [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for more [information](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401), which, for half-integer values of *n*, can be reduced to $$\dfrac{(ab)^m}{c^{2m+1}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{e^{2ab}}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^m\dfrac{(m+k)!}{(m-k)!}\cdot\dfrac{(4ab)^{-k}}{k!},$$ with $m=|n|-\dfrac12$ and $c=a$ for $n<\dfrac12$ and $c=b$ for $n\ge\dfrac12.$

Comment: As usual, [*OEIS*](http://oeis.org/A043302) was essential in deducing the general formula.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Laplace transform of $t^{-3/2} e^{-1/t}$.  I would evaluate as follows: sub $t=1/u$ to get

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{du}{u^2} u^{3/2} e^{-u} e^{-p/u} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv \, e^{-(v^2 + p/v^2)} = e^{-2 \sqrt{p}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv \, e^{-\left (v-\sqrt{p}/v \right )^2 }$$

Let $v=p^{1/4} y$; then the integral is

$$p^{1/4} e^{-2 \sqrt{p}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv \, e^{-\sqrt{p} (y-1/y)^2}$$

Now, for well-behaved, even-valued functions $f$, i.e. integrable,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \, f \left ( y-\frac1{y} \right ) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \, f \left ( y \right ) $$

Thus, the integral is

$$p^{1/4} e^{-2 \sqrt{p}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv \, e^{-\sqrt{p} y^2} $$

Finally,

> $$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, t^{-3/2} \, e^{-1/t} e^{-p t} = \sqrt{\pi} \, e^{-2 \sqrt{p}} $$

**ADDENDUM**

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \, f \left ( y-\frac1{y} \right ) = \int_0^{\infty} dy \, f \left ( y-\frac1{y} \right ) + \int_{-\infty}^0 dy \, f \left ( y-\frac1{y} \right )$$

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dy \, f \left ( y-\frac1{y} \right ) &= \int_0^{1} dy \, f \left ( y-\frac1{y} \right ) + \int_1^{\infty} dy \, f \left ( y-\frac1{y} \right )\\ &= \int_1^{\infty} dy \, \left (1+\frac1{y^2} \right ) f \left ( y-\frac1{y} \right ) \\ &= \int_1^{\infty} d \left (y - \frac1{y} \right ) \, f \left ( y-\frac1{y} \right ) \\ &= \int_0^{\infty} dy \, f(y) \end{align}$$

Similar for $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \, f \left ( y-\frac1{y} \right ) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \, f \left ( y \right )

Comment: @math.: see edit.

Comment: @math.: "well-behaved, **even-valued** functions"