# How do you integrate cos(cos x)?

Tags: integration

I started with the definition / alternative form of $\cos(x) := \frac{1}{2} \cdot (e^{-ix} + e^{ix})$ and nested it $\frac{1}{2} \cdot (e^{-\frac{1}{2}i(e^{-ix} + e^{ix})} + e^{\frac{1}{2}i(e^{-ix} + e^{ix})})$

Well and now I'm a little bit overwhelmed what to do next and how to integrate it. Is there a trick?

Comment: I don't think this function can be integrated in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: *How do you integrate* $\cos(\cos x)$ ? - [Like this...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401) :-$)$

Comment: What makes you think such an integral even exists? I'm about 99% sure there is no integral in elementary functions.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't know of an integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't (in terms of elementary functions).

Unless a power series will do...

$$\cos (1) (x-\pi ) +\frac{1}{6} \sin (1)(x-\pi )^3  +
   \left(-\frac{\sin (1)}{120}-\frac{\cos (1)}{40}\right)(x-\pi )^5 + \left(\frac{\cos (1)}{336}-\frac{\sin (1)}{360}\right)(x-\pi )^7 + \frac{209 \sin (1)+42 \cos(1)}{362880}(x-\pi )^9  +  \dots $$

Warning:  the rate of convergence is not particularly good...