# Compute the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(1+\cos^2x)\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

My attempt.
$$\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\sin(1+\cos^2x)\mathrm{d}x $$
Let $t=1+\cos^2x \Rightarrow \mathrm{d}t -2\sin x\cos x~ \mathrm{d}x. $
We have $\cos^2x=t-1 \Rightarrow \cos x=\sqrt{t-1}$ and $\sin x = \sqrt{2-t}.$ So $$\mathrm{d}x = \frac{-\mathrm{d}t}{2\sqrt{2-t}\sqrt{t-1}}$$
Now,
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_1^2\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{2-t}\sqrt{t-1}}\mathrm{d}t$$
I tried substituting by parts letting $u=\sin t$, and $dv = \int \mathrm{d}t/(\sqrt{(2-t)(t-1)})$.

But the integral just gets more complicated.

Comment: I think this integral can't  nice closed form

Comment: If you hope for an answer in elementary functions, you may just as well abandon your hopes right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [integral representations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401) of the [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the first kind at $0$,

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\left(z\cos \theta\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}J_0\left(z\right).$$

So,

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin\left(1+\cos^2x\right)\mathrm{d}x&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2x\right)+\frac{3}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sin\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2x\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x+\cos\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\underset{0}{\underbrace{\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(2x\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)J_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, pretty fast hah ?

Answer (score 4):

$$
I=\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{i(1+\cos^2(x))}=\Im \left(e^{i\frac 32}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{\frac i2\cos(2x)}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\Im\left( e^{i\frac 32}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\frac i2\cos(x)}\right)\underbrace{=}_{(\star)}\frac{\pi}{2}J_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Im (e^{i\frac 32})=\frac{\pi}{2}J_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)
$$

where $J_0(z)$ is a Bessel function of the first type and equation $(\star)$ frollows [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel.27s_integrals)

Comment: it must be $\sin\left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )$

Comment: @Renascence_5. Sure, thanks for catching the error

Comment: I am glad to be wrong when I look at the beauty of your solution (which I upvoted, for sure) ! Cheers.

Comment: After my shame and your approach $$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\sin \left(a+b \cos ^2(x)\right)\,dx=\frac{\pi  }{2} J_0\left(\frac{b}{2}\right) \sin \left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici very nice generalization...intersting because i thought my solution would build up on a very special trig identity

Answer (score 0):

I took an approach (below) but then dropped the idea to continue since the other answers were so neat and beautiful to follow and mine was a lot of work, which I shall complete at a later point of time (I hope at least). I hence write what I have so far below

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}(2x)dx&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}(x)dx\\
&=\frac12\text{Beta}(\frac12,n+\frac12)
\end{align}
hence \begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(1+\cos^2x)\mathrm{d}x &=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m(1+\cos^2x)^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)!}\int_0^{\pi/2}(1+\cos^2x)^{2m+1}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)!}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sum_{j=0}^{2m+1}{2k+1\choose j} \cos^{2j}(x) \mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2m+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{2m+1}{2m+1\choose j}\int_0^{\pi/2}  \cos^{2j}(x) \mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2m+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{2m+1}{2m+1\choose j}\frac12\text{Beta}(\frac12,j+\frac12)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2m+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{2m+1}{2m+1\choose j}\frac12\pi\frac{(2j-1)!!}{2^jj!}\\
&=\frac12\pi\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{2m+1}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2m+1-j)!}\frac{(2j-1)!!}{2^jj!^2}\\
\end{align}