# Problem with integral of hyperbolic function

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

I am stuck on taking the integral of this:

$$\int \sin(9\sinh(2x))\,{\rm d}x$$

I tried using using a double $u$ substitution, but i got confused. Nothing seems to cancel out.

Comment: This does not look like an integral that has an elementrary antiderivative.

Comment: how would i start solving it?

Comment: You can likely find a solution in the form of a power-series. I might be wrong, but I won't expect this to have a simple closed form solution.

Comment: See [Bessel and Struve functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401).

Answer (score 0):

In [general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401), $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\sin(a~\sinh t)~dt~=~\dfrac\pi2~\Big(I_0(a)-L_0(a)\Big),~$ where ***I*** and ***L*** represent the [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function), respectively. Letting $t=2x$ and $a=9$ should therefore yield a closed form expression for the *definite* integral in terms of these two special functions. However, evaluating the *indefinite* integral would require the existence of “incomplete” Bessel and Struve functions, which, unfortunately, do not formally exist $($as a conventional object of study within the larger realm of mathematics$)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\int\sin(9\sinh2x)~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n9^{2n+1}\sinh^{2n+1}2x}{(2n+1)!}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n9^{2n+1}\sinh^{2n}2x}{2(2n+1)!}~d(\cosh2x)$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n9^{2n+1}(\cosh^22x-1)^n}{2(2n+1)!}~d(\cosh2x)$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{2n-k}9^{2n+1}C_k^n\cosh^{2k}2x}{2(2n+1)!}~d(\cosh2x)$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^k9^{2n+1}n!\cosh^{2k+1}2x}{2(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$