# Evaluating closed form of $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2} \underbrace{\cos(\cos(\dots(\cos}_{n \text{ times}}(x))\dots))~dx$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> I was wondering if there is any way to evaluate a general closed form solution to the following integral for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
>   $$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2} \underbrace{\cos(\cos(\cos(\dots(\cos}_{n \text{ times}}(x))\dots)))~dx \tag{1}$$

I have already evaluated closed forms to this integral for certain values of $n$, however I am still missing a closed form for a large number of values of $n$. Those in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ I numerically evaluated, meaning that I currently do not have a closed form for them.
$$\begin{array}{c|c}n&I_n\\\hline0&\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}\\1&1\\2&\dfrac{\pi J_0(1)}{2}\\\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{\approx 1.11805}\\\color{red}{4}&\color{red}{\approx 1.18186} \\ \color{red}{5} & \color{red}{\approx 1.14376} \\ \color{red}{6}&\color{red}{\approx 1.17102}\\\color{red}{\vdots}&\color{red}{\vdots}\\\infty&\alpha\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2} \approx 1.16095\end{array}$$
Where $J_p(\cdot )$ is the [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), and $\alpha$ is the [Dottie Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html). The cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ are trivial, hence I will not show how I derived these solutions. Hence, I will show how I derived the case where $n=2$ and $n\to \infty$.

---

**Evaluating $I_2$: i.e $\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(\cos(x))~dx$.**

Introducing the definition of the Bessel Function of the first kind:
$$J_{\beta}(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(z\sin{\theta}-\beta \theta)~d\theta$$
We can use the substitution $\theta=u+\frac{\pi}{2}$ to obtain:

$$\begin{align} J_{\beta}(z)&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos\left(z\sin\left(u+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\beta\left(u+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)~du\\&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos\left(z\cos(u)-\beta\left(u+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)~du \end{align}$$
To get it into a similar form to our case, notice that we can let $\beta=0$ and $z=1$. Therefore:
$$J_0(1)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos(\cos(u))~du$$
At first sight, it may seem like the bounds are problematic. However, note that $f(x)=\cos(\cos(x))$ is an even function, hence we know that:
$$J_0(1)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(\cos(u))~du \iff \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(\cos(u))~du=\frac{\pi J_0(1)}{2}$$

---

**Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} I_n$:**

I realized that as $n\to \infty$, the integrand will converge to a constant function for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, as shown below. The blue, yellow, green and red curves is when $n=1,2,5,10$ respectively.

[image]

I figured that we can represent the repeated composition of functions by the following recurrence $x_{n+1}=\cos(x_n)$. Using the principles of fixed point iteration, we know thus know that the value it tends to is the unique solution to $x=\cos(x)$. This turns out to be the [Dottie Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html), which I evaluated numerically using the [Newton-Raphson Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) and denoted this value by $\alpha$. I obtained:
$$\alpha\approx 0.739085133215161$$
Hence:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(\cos(\cos(\dots(\cos(x))\dots)))~dx=\alpha\cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \approx 1.160952212443092$$

---

As mentioned, I am unsure how to evaluate closed forms for the cases when $n\geq 3$. I've checked some other definitions such as the [Struve function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) $\mathbf{H}_{\gamma}(\cdot)$, though it only seems to be useful when evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(\sin(x))~dx$, which is not the integral we are considering. Hence, I would appreciate some guidance on how to evaluate a general closed form for $(1)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, if possible.

Comment: I sincerely doubt this can be written exactly for general $n$

Comment: Try: to generate a sequence from Chebyshev polynomials. Good Luck

Comment: If $n=0$, shouldn't the result be $\pi/2$ since no cosines means that the integrand is one?

Comment: @martycohen I took $n=0$ as this instead, though maybe I shouldn't have: $$\int_0^{\pi/2} x~dx=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

Comment: @projectilemotion There may be a way to evaluate the general $n$ case as $n-2$ series expansions, not a closed form, but it is an exact form. This uses repeated application of [this expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion). Would you like this possible answer?

Comment: With Mathematica **13.3.0** `N[RealInverseSphericalBesselY[0, -1, 1]]` gives: $0.739085$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Indeed, but that is also expected since
$$y_0(x)=-\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\, ,$$
and ``RealInverseSphericalBesselY[n, t, b]`` means you consider $n$ as the order of
the inverted function $y_n$, $t$ as the value of $y_n$, and $b$ is the branch number of the countably infinite branch numbers of the inverse. So here one essentially asks Mathematica to solve $\cos(x)=x$.

Comment: @projectilemotion I forgot to add that `RealInverseSphericalBesselY` works with `AskConstants 5.0` packages from here: https://math.hawaii.edu/~dale/AskConstants/AskConstants.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mere fact that even the simple [case](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401) $n=2$ ceases to possess a meaningful closed form in terms of *elementary* functions, and an *entirely new function* had to be invented from *scratch* in order to express its value, should be enough to settle all questions one might have concerning the possibility of finding such a form for larger values of the argument. Indeed, the very next case, $n=3,$ is not known to be expressible even in terms of *special* functions. That $\cos^{[\infty]}(x)$ is a constant $($since the function is both bound and monotone$)$ certainly constitutes a blessing, but such clearly does not hold for *finite* values of the iterator. $($ See also [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) $).$